# Find Array Item Number in a For Statement

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm using a for statement to loop through items in an array to find the item's value. On occasion however, I need to find out what that item's count is in the array (not just the item value), but can't seem to figure out how to do this. Below is what I've been trying which has given me some sort of result, but not what I need, everything else I've tried has resulted in an error:

```
for elements in myArray {

   println(elements) // gives me the value
   println(elements.items) // gives me nil

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well an easy way to do that is:

```
for index in 0..<myArray.count {
    println(myArray[index]) // value
    println(index) // count
}
```

If you know what kind of value you're looking for, you can also use the `find()` method:

```
let value = 13
if let index = find(myArray, value) {
    println(myArray[index]) // item in the array with the value you were searching for
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an easy way of getting what I need. I need the index to find whether I'm at the start or end of myarray.

Comment: If this answered the question, mind to mark it as answered? :)

Comment: Yep, will do, it said I had to wait 8 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` to get the elements of an array (or any
sequence) together with the corresponding index:

```
for (index, element) in enumerate(myArray) {
    println(element) // current element
    println(index)   // index of current element
}
```